# Hiding a QtMainWindow tab in a GUI?

Tags: python, qt4, pyqt4

I've a GUI (written in PyQt) with three tabs, each a QtGui.QMainWindow class. The whole GUI is defined by a .ui file. That seems to be the main difference between the similar questions on SO (links in next paragraph) where people are looking to hide a QMainWindow object. More specifically, that I'm trying to hide a QMainWindow object that's part of (not the whole) Gui element.

The main window and its tabs look like this:

[image]

Depending on a setting in my config file, I want to either leave TEST visible, or hide it from the user. I've checked both the [PyQT Docs](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qmainwindow.html) (ie `removeDockWidget()`?) and there are two similar SO queries ([Link One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22538247/pyqt-how-to-hide-qmainwindow) and [link Two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38739009/pyqt-hide-mainwindow-and-show-qdialog-without-the-taskbar-icon-disappearing?noredirect=1&lq=1)), and a SO Question suggesting [layouts/setVisible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11826036/pyside-show-hide-layouts)..

But I can't get it right. If I use `.hide()` or `.setVisible(False)` then nothing seems to change. If I set `.setVisible(True)` then an additional, miniature window appears on startup, with the name of my main class.

The structure of my code is:

My entry/main class:

```
class Gui:
    def __init__(self):
        # Create the main window GUI and show it
        self.mainWindow= GuiMainWindow(self)
        self.mainWindow.show()
    <...>        

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)  
    myGui = Gui(app)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

GuiMainWindow contain the three tabs:

```
class GuiMainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, appMain):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        # Create helper objects to manage main window tabs
        self.daqTab = GuiMainDaqTab(appMain, self)
        self.pwrTab = GuiMainPowerTab(appMain, self)
        self.testTab = GuiMainTestTab(appMain, self)

        self.testTab.hideMe()
```

Finally, the TEST tab is what I want to hide/show:

```
class GuiMainTestTab(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, appMain, mainWindow):
        super(GuiMainTestTab, self).__init__()
        self.appMain = appMain
        self.mainWindow = mainWindow
        self.ui = mainWindow.ui
        <...>

    def hideMe(self):  
        self.close()
    #   self.hide()             # Also tried hide()
    #   self.setVisible(False)  # ..Or setVisible()
```

**--- Edit to assist the answer / my match comment to answer below ---**

So, the class `GuiMainTestTab` accesses the contents of the ui file through its member `self.ui`. Digging through the ui file I found that `testTab` is its name of the Test tab in the ui file (as opposed to `testTab` in `GuiMainWindow`..!). It's attached to a QTabWidget called verticalTabWidget. So to programmatically find Test tab's index, and remove it:

```
        testIdx = self.ui.verticalTabWidget.indexOf(self.ui.testTab)
        self.ui.verticalTabWidget.removeTab(testIdx)
```

Comment: Please read the guidance on how to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`QWidget`](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qwidget.html)-based actions like `close()`, `hide()`, `setVisible(True)` are not effecting your [`QTabWidget`](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qtabwidget.html)-container, just the containing page (tab). 
Since `show`, `hide` and other Access-functions for the [visibility-property](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#visible-prop) are also used by the container, your changes are overwriten later.

*You can see this by calling `testTab.show()` while an other Tab is active.*

---

to hide the Tab from the user, you can either:

- simply not create/add him on start (modifying your `setupUi()`-function)
- remove the tab from the Container ([`QTabWidget`](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qtabwidget.html)) by using:
  [`tabWidget.removeTab(index)`](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qtabwidget.html#removeTab)

here is a minimal working example using the second approach:

```
def main ( ) :
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
    app = QApplication( [] )
    window = Test_Dialog()
    window.show()
    exit( app.exec() )

class Ui_Dialog( object ) :
    def setupUi ( self, Dialog ) :
        from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget( Dialog )
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry( QtCore.QRect( 9, 9, 181, 121 ) )
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.pushButton_remove = QtWidgets.QPushButton( "remove", self.tab )
        self.pushButton_remove.setGeometry( QtCore.QRect( 20, 10, 75, 23 ) )
        self.pushButton_add = QtWidgets.QPushButton( "add", self.tab )
        self.pushButton_add.setGeometry( QtCore.QRect( 20, 60, 75, 23 ) )
        self.tabWidget.addTab( self.tab, "Tab 1" )
        self.tab_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit( self.tab_2 )
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry( QtCore.QRect( 30, 30, 113, 20 ) )
        self.tabWidget.addTab( self.tab_2, "Tab 2" )  # remove this for approach #1

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog
class Test_Dialog( QDialog, Ui_Dialog ) :
    def __init__ ( self ) :
        QDialog.__init__( self )
        self.setupUi( self )
        self.pushButton_remove.clicked.connect( self.hideTab )
        self.pushButton_add.clicked.connect( self.showTab )
    def hideTab ( self ) :
        self.save = self.tabWidget.widget( 1 )  # save it for later
        self.tabWidget.removeTab( 1 )
    def showTab ( self ) :
        self.tabWidget.insertTab( 1, self.save, 'Tab2 is here again' ) # restore
```

simply use [`QTabWidget.remove()`](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qtabwidget.html#removeTab) and [`QTabWidget.insert()`](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qtabwidget.html#insertTab) or [`QTabWidget.addTab()`](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qtabwidget.html#addTab) and you even can still access erverything as normal, if you need something from the "hidden" tab.

*I added a QLineEdit on "Tab 2" to show that no datas are lost when removing, just type something in there and try it.*

Comment: please note my sample is writen with `pyqt5`, but it should be completly compatible qith `pyqt4` -> simply switch the number

Comment: Thank you, that works! - I would only add that you can programmatically find the index of the tab to be "hidden". Use `QTabWidget.indexOf(testTab)` where `testTab` is the QtGui.QWidget within the ui file. So in my (snipped) example code, `Ui_MainWindow` is the class defined in the ui file (which I excluded from my post). `testTab` would therefore be `self.ui.testTab`.

Comment: That's a bit messy, I'll add a few lines to my original post to make things clearer.